# Accessing more than one account same time in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

To go another account in Windows 10, either we do sign out one account or use switch user.

Is there any way in Windows 10 so that we can enable accessing more than one user account same time in Windows 10?

If yes, please let me know, how?

Best Regards
FewL

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot do that. You must log off and sign in as another account.

You can RDP in but that logs the other user out. You can use Radmin server and access the user’s session at the same time for support like Team Viewer.

But without that, only one user at a time in Windows workstation

Comment: As you said, You can RDP in but that logs the other user out. You can use Radmin server and access the user’s session at the same time for support like Team Viewer. If there are two user accounts A and B, I logged in A then switched to B account. Please elaborate, what I need to do that you explained.

Comment: If you load Radmin Server on the first computer, the second can access it with Radmin Viewer.  Then the second computer can see the first and manage the first. I do this. So you could switch users on the first computer this way

Comment: As you said, first computer and second computer but I was saying more one user account in a single computer. Will that work in this case?

Comment: You have to switch users. One user account can only allow one user no matter how do it. Windows has been this way for a long time.  As noted, with Radmin or Team Viewer, one user can be remote and share the session with the user physically on the computer.  You can have as many user accounts as you practically need on one computer. That works, but you must switch between them (log off one, log one the other)

Comment: In case of Team Viewer, Team Viewer ID is same in all user account. If I switched from user account A to user account B, now I am in B, how to connect user account A screen with Team Viewer?

Comment: I think you need to let the person running Team Viewer to do the switching. If the subject switches user accounts the Teem Viewer host's session will likely disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

how about good old “runas” command? it’s still there in windows 10 and allows to execute commands as different user. 
Start command prompt, type “runas”, Enter to see options.